# After submit a form, stay same page, show a word in the page

Tags: javascript, html

1. After clicking "submit", stay on the page.
2. Input data, like "computer number" and "profit", stay inside those blank square.
3. A word "Submitted", appear in the center of this page.

The following is my code, Please help, thank you!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

  <body>

  <form name="form" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
   
    Computer Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Computer" required><br>
  
<p>How much is your profit?                                 

<input id="id1" name = "id1" required>
  <button  type = "button" onclick="myFunction()">My Answer</button> 
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="Solution()" style="display:none;">Solution</button>
    </p>

<p id="Q1"></p>

<script>
var errosCount = 0;
  function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("id1").value;
   
    if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
        text = "Incorrect"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";errosCount++;
    } else {
        text = "Correct"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
    }
    document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
         if(errosCount === 3){
        errosCount = 0;
        document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = '';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'none';        
      } 
}
function Solution(){
  text = "(P - w) * q<sub>o</sub> - I = (53 - 43) * 30 - 200 = 100";  document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
}      
</script>
 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
</form>
  
  <script>
function validateForm() {
    var q = document.forms["my form"]["Computer"].value;
    if (q == "") {
        alert("Computer Number is Missing!");
        return false;}
  var w = document.forms["my form"]["id1"].value;
    if (w != "100") {
        alert("Question 1 is Incorrect!");
        return false;}
  
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you were having `document.forms["my form"]` which was invalid since your form name was `form` so I changed it to `document.forms["form"]`.

And, on submit, I added `return false` at the bottom of the function to stay on the page. Also, before that, added "Submitted" text in the center of the page as shown below.

Here's working code snippet!

Hope that helps!

```js
var errosCount = 0;

function myFunction() {
  var x, text;
  x = document.getElementById("id1").value;

  if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
    text = "Incorrect";
    document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
    errosCount++;
  } else {
    text = "Correct";
    document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
  }
  document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
  if (errosCount === 3) {
    errosCount = 0;
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function Solution() {
  text = "(P - w) * q<sub>o</sub> - I = (53 - 43) * 30 - 200 = 100";
  document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
}

function validateForm() {
  var q = document.forms["form"]["Computer"].value;
  if (q == "") {
    alert("Computer Number is Missing!");
    return false;
  }
  var w = document.forms["form"]["id1"].value;
  if (w != "100") {
    alert("Question 1 is Incorrect!");
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("submitted").innerHTML = "Submitted"
  return false;
}
```

```css
#submitted {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  Computer Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Computer"><br>

  <p>How much is your profit?

    <input id="id1" name="id1" required>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">My Answer</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="Solution()" style="display:none;">Solution</button>
  </p>

  <p id="Q1"></p>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
<br/>
<div id="submitted">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should think abut using AJAX as you are sending a form.

This can be the button:

```
    <button type="button"
    onclick="validateForm('ajax_info.php', myFunction)"> Clic to Submit
    </button>
```

And this the AJAX function:

```js
      function validateForm(url, cFunction) {
      var xhttp;
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          cFunction(this);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", url, true); //can be POST
      xhttp.send();
    }
    function myFunction(xhttp) {
      document.getElementById("submited").innerHTML =
      xhttp.responseText;
    }
```

Comment: Your function names are mismatched. (Also, `evaluate` is a very undescriptive name.)